# VSTS - Xamarin iOS Build- Nuget Restore Step Error

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines

I've setup a build in VSTS whose first step is to restore nuget packages.
Everything worked fine until today. I don't think that I've done anything by coding so I don't understand wy I get this error today:

MsBuild.exe does not exist at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5/msbuild.exe'

I don't understand how this works but when I saw this error I tried to cheat: I located a folder for MSBuild 14.1,  took everything and copied it into /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5/.

However Now I have the following error:
MSBUILD : error MSB1005: Specify a property and its value.